# IE8 Not Calling Two JavaScript Functions via Onclick Event

Tags: javascript, function, events, internet-explorer-8, onclick

Essentially I want to call two functions on onClick event. Works fine in firefox and chrome but NOT IE8!

The first function should call for the modal to appear (modal indicates that the form is in the process of being saved - but it is not appearing) while the second function saves the form and then hide the modal.

**HTML**

```
<a onclick="openModal();saveForm();">Click Me</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div id="modal">
        <img id="loader" src="static/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
   function openModal(){
       $('#myModal').modal('show');
   }

   function saveForm(){
    //--- some logic
   }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: And how do you know that `func1` is not *called*?

Comment: If you put an `alert()` in `func1`, do you see it?

Comment: Did you know .... wait for it .... that jQuery has a pretty fancy spanking way to add event handlers without using inline javascript ?

Comment: @adeneo: You are not talking about http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/, are you adeneo? That is amazing!

Comment: Binding your element using JS instead of `onclick` attribute is recommended and would remove the issue. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: My apologies - I have modified my code (please view above). Once a user clicks on the link, a modal should appear while the form gets saved.

Comment: Are you sure that the function is not called (like Barmar said, what happens if you add an alert)? Maybe the `.modal()` method just doesn't work well with IE8 (you know, animations and stuff).

Comment: It works fine in IE. Works fine too if I just call the openModal();. But will not work if I call two functions.

Comment: Have you tried calling a single function on `onclick` and then calling the other function inside it. Like [THIS](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CbsLw)

Comment: What does `saveForm()` do? Does it hide the modal?

Comment: Thanks - I've tried that. Alert seems to be work fine but bootstrap modal will not.

Comment: saveForm will save the form first and then hide the modal. Works fine in other browsers.

Comment: Displaying a modal DIV doesn't cause the script to wait for the user to fill it in. `saveForm()` will run immediately after the modal is displayed, save the form, and hide the modal before the user has a chance to see the modal.

Comment: The modal appears to indicate that the form is in the process of being saved.

ex: http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/jQuery-Plugin-For-Checking-Content-Has-Been-Loaded-is-loading.jpg

Answer (score -1):

I personally don’t like it to listen to an event by adding the "onclick" attribute to an HTML element. Instead, it would be more practical to use .addEventListener. I can also really recommend you [jQuery](http://jquery.com). In jQuery, you would write:

```
$('a').click(function(){
  func1();
  func2();
}
```

Comment: This is a stylistic preference. Why do you think it will solve whatever problem he's having with the original code?

Comment: Well, at least it’s worth trying that, when it doesn’t work with his version for whatever reason @Barmar

Comment: If you're trying to solve the problem, recoding it like this is just a waste of time. There's absolutely no way that it could change the behavior.